# is this type notation in the Vue decorator constructor correct?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, decorator

I used Vue decorator notation like this:

```
@Prop({ type: Object || null, default: null })
```

in Vue documentation I saw notation by array:

```
@Prop({ type: [ Object, null ], default: null })
```

but does the notation through the sign || is that wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### You can use it like so, but it's not the right way.

See [**Logical OR (||)**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_OR). If you set `null || Object` you will get `Object`, because `Boolean(null)` is `false`. In your variation you will get `Object` because `Boolean(Object)` is `true`. But you can use it like this:

```js
@Prop({ type: Object, default: null })
```

Not only in an array way (`[Object]`).